# Cálculo de salário precisa limitar casas

Tags: python, matemática, formatação

> Um funcionário de uma empresa recebe aumento salarial anualmente: Sabe-se que:
>
> Esse funcionário foi contratado em 1995, com salário inicial de R$ 1.000,00;
>
> Em 1996 recebeu aumento de 1,5% sobre seu salário inicial;
>
> A partir de 1997 (inclusive), os aumentos salariais sempre correspondem ao dobro do percentual do ano anterior.
>
> Faça um programa que determine o salário atual desse funcionário.
>
> Após concluir isto, altere o programa permitindo que o usuário digite o salário inicial do funcionário.

Meu código:

```py
salario = int(input('Digite o salário do funcionário: '))
ano = 1996
porcentagem = 1.5/100
salario_1 = salario
while ano <= 2020:
    salario = salario + (porcentagem * salario_1)
    ano += 1
    porcentagem += porcentagem
print(salario)
```

A minha real dúvida é como limitar o print de um número inteiro (Ex.1234567, e só aparecer --> 123), pois a saída do meu código sai meio estranho as vezes.
Com o salário sendo 1000, a saída é: 503317465.0 (e eu duvido que esse seja mesmo o resultado certo).

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo

Answer (score 4):

Tem alguns problemas nesse código. Além de complexo demais ele não faz o que o enunciado pede e produz o resultado correto. A questão da formatação é só um ponto que não fará ele estar correto.

Tem várias formas de formatar, vou colocar uma, não é a mais moderna, mas o código todo não é o mais idiomático mesmo. Assim como dá para usar uma fórmula mais elaborada, mas acredito que não seja o objetivo.

Só lembrando que para valores monetários reais não pode fazer desta forma, já que Python tem por padrão tipo numérico com tipo flutuante binário que não tem exatidão e eles não se prestam para se esse tipo de tarefa, teria que usar outro tipo ou fazer malabarismo com inteiro (que nem funcionaria quando pede entrada de dado simples), mas para exercício está ok.

```
salario = 1000
ano = 1996
while ano <= 2020:
    salario *= 1.015
    ano += 1
print("{0:.2f}".format(salario, 2))
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/lSK58j). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/Payrollpy). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Algorithm/Payroll.py).

Quando o exercício é dado assim ele faz pouco sentido porque você não precisa de um código para fazer isso, você tem todos os dados e pode ser calculado sem código, mas se for fazer o código eu faria da forma mais simples possível, apenas artificialmente mantendo os valores já sabidos para calcular, então usaria a fórmula de juros composto.

```
print(f"{1000 * (1.015 ** (2020 - 1996 + 1)):.2f}")
```

E dando continuidade ao que pede depois poderia fazer só isto:

```
print(f"{int(input('Digite o salário do funcionário: ')) * 1.45095:.2f}")
```

Não tratei possível erro de digitação que invalidaria a entrada e geraria exceção.

Comment: E teria uma dica de como deixar o código mais idiomático?

Comment: Isso seria outra questão e mudaria tudo, eu coloquei a forma com f strings para ajudar, e o laço seria feito com `for`, mas na verdade o exercício é ruim porque ele não precisa de código, aí eu tenho que artificialmente impor um limite até onde eu vou reduzindo. Se reduzir até o limite nada precisa ser escrito. Eu fiz um agora usando fórmula, mas eu acho que não era o objeto, culpa do exercício ser ruim. Aí teria que começar inventar imposições só para fazer dar certo.

Comment: só lembrando que se você quiser números decimais exatos em Python eles estão disponíveis no módulo `decimal`, então a frase "porque Python tem números com tipo flutuante binário que não tem exatidão e não se presta para se esse tipo de tarefa" está incorreta. E mesmo que não houvesse o módulo decimal, tradicionalmente se emula um valor monetário com ponto fixo usando um inteiro, o que permite contas monetárias em praticamente qualquer linguagem, inclusive C ou Python - mas os inteiros sem limite de tamanho facilitam muito as coisas nessa abordagem.

Comment: Então quer dizer que Python **não** tem números com tipo flutuante binário? Seria a única forma da minha afirmação está errada. A única afirmação que eu fiz é que tem. Eu não disse que não dá para fazer de outra forma e obter o resultado correto.

Comment: Python usa ponto flutnte binário padrão do "double' do compilador C usado. A afirmaçãoque você fez é aa que eu coloquei entre aspas - e a leitura é que o sujeito da parte que  termina em "...e não se presta para esse tipo de tarefa" é a  linguagem, e não o tipo de dado. 
Na frase como está, se trocar Python por : "porque essa linguagem tem números com tipo flutuante binário que não tem exatidão e não se presta para se esse tipo de tarefa" - qual linguagem **não** se enquadraria? Cobol, talvez.

Comment: Pinçar uma parte do texto para fazer sua afirmação ser verdade não é algo muito justo, o texto estava lá inteiro, para ser interpretado como um todo não só com uma parte.